# Set static IP for virtual machine on centos

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

I need to set static IP addresses on my virtual machines in VirtualBox.
My host OS - Ubuntu, guest OS - CentOS 7. And the main condition - I have to ping my guest machines from a host (and they have to ping each other).
As far as I understand, I need to use the bridged adapter. But how configure CentOS to has static IP address (for ping)?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add virtual NIC to your Guest CentOS7.
Next install `NetworkManager-tui` package via CentOS iso image.
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Networking Guide helps you.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Networking_Config_Using_nmtui.html

Here is another sample:
https://lintut.com/how-to-setup-network-after-rhelcentos-7-minimal-installation/

Comment: If you can provide more details, the link with time might break or change